# How do I create a new signal in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gobject

I've created a python object, but I want to send signals on it.  I made it inherit from gobject.GObject, but there doesn't seem to be any way to create a new signal on my object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also define signals inside the class definition:

```
class MyGObjectClass(gobject.GObject):
    __gsignals__ = {
      "some-signal": (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, (object, )),
    }
```

The contents of the tuple are the the same as the three last arguments to `gobject.signal_new`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how:

```
import gobject

class MyGObjectClass(gobject.GObject):
    ...

gobject.signal_new("signal-name", MyGObjectClass, gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
    None, (str, int))
```

Where the second to last argument is the return type and the last argument is a tuple of argument types.

Answer (score 2):

If you use kiwi available [here](http://kiwi.async.com.br/) you can just do:

```
from kiwi.utils import gsignal

class MyObject(gobject.GObject):
    gsignal('signal-name')
```