# How to create a gsignal without parameters in pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk, signals, gobject, pygobject

The [pygtk signal documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm#d0e570) is pretty clear about signals creation, but I could not create a signal that doesn't take parameters.

What I want is to [define (like in the example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66730/how-do-i-create-a-new-signal-in-pygtk):

```
class MyGObjectClass(gobject.GObject):
    __gsignals__ = {
      "some-signal": (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, gobject.TYPE_NONE),
    }
```

and then call:

```
self.emit('some-signal') # not passing any arguments
```

Currently I can't do this, since the third parameter for gsignal_new is required, and can't be None.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an empty tuple as the third argument.

```
__gsignals__ = {
  "some-signal": (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, ()),
}
```